# How to enable adbd to listen to a port at boot time in Android?

Tags: android, adb, boot, init, remote-connection

I have a rooted HTC Hero, and what I want to do is to enable the adbd
to listen to a port at boot time.

I tried some code found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=635102):

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

in an Android shell and it works great.

I tried to change the **init.rc** file. I added the above code in init.rc
and I replaced it with the original file, through these commands:

```
adb push init.rc sdcard

adb shell
adb su
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /
adb cp sdcard/init.rc /
```

The file is replaced successfully, but when I reboot my phone and try to connect
through:

```
adb connect <IP>:5555
```

the connection is not being established.

Any ideas?

(PS. I don't want to use the [remoteADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jaja.remoteadb&hl=en) application and a shell command like
    `am start -n ...`
)

Comment: This will surely help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768103/make-persistent-changes-to-init-rc

Comment: This is for enabling ADB connection without USB at all - [android - Adb over network without previous USB pairing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746917/adb-over-network-without-previous-usb-pairing/15747430#15747430)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This will make it persistent:

```
setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555
```

ADB *over USB* might not be available after reboot. To undo this setting, do:

```
setprop persist.adb.tcp.port ""
```

Comment: You have no idea how much this find has saved our bacon - so simple & works - why has this not gotten more up-votes? Cheers.

Comment: Where are these properties stored? Compared to build.prop?

Comment: On my Sony Xperia Z1 compact with stock ROM Android 5.0.2 the USB keeps working even after reboot.

Comment: If you are using adb, the command is `adb shell setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555`.

Comment: You sir are awesome sauce :) I know this is old but still very useful!

Comment: I needed a nuance - First 
`adb shell`
then 
`su`
then 
`setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555`

Comment: useless for me :setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555; setprop persist.sys.start.adb 1 \n\n

Comment: @JohnyTex persistent properties are stored in /data/property/persistent_properties

Comment: Great! Will it work without root?

Comment: @Giorgio no, to run `setprop` root is required

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack, modify, and repack the initrd inside the boot.img. You can find more on this at:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/w37x_WCrhMM

Answer (score 0):

Root is required.

To set this property by [Termux](https://github.com/termux) terminal:

```
su -c "setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555"
```

To restart `adb` (for making changed port updated in it) by Termux:

```
su -c "stop adbd && start adbd"
```

To check property (root is not needed):

```
getprop persist.adb.tcp.port
getprop service.adb.tcp.port
```

To unset property:

```
su -c "setprop persist.adb.tcp.port ''"
```

USB ADB is also working even if property `persist.adb.tcp.port` is set to 5555. Checked on Android 9, MIUI 11 64 bit.

(query for search engines: how to change android system property in termux)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try using a `BroadcastReceiver` of the action `BOOT_COMPLETED`?

You can register one in you Manifest:

```
        <receiver
        android:name="com.myapp.BootCompleted"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and in the class you can do whatever you want when boot is completed:

```
import java.util.*;
import android.content.*;

public class BootCompleted extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // Do the actions you want
    }
}
```