# How to stop adb wireless programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I want to start and stop adb wireless from an app using a rooted phone. I managed to start adb wireless daemon with these commands:

```
            String cmds[] = {
                    "setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555",
                    "stop adbd",
                    "start adbd"
            };
            Shell.su(cmds).exec();
```

But

```
            String cmds[] = {
                    "stop adbd"
            };
            Shell.su(cmds).exec();
```

or

```
            String cmds[] = {
                    "setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555",
                    "stop adbd"
            };
            Shell.su(cmds).exec();
```

does not work to stop adb. At least it stops but I can't start it again with

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

How should I stop adb wireless properly from a rooted phone?

Comment: tried `adb kill-server && start-server` ?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I don't want to stop start adb from laptop. I want to stop and start adb wireless daemon at android phone. I edited my question to explain my question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but try removing the 5555 as a parameter (maybe passing an empty string in quotes, or passing nothing at all).

It smells a lot as this answer (although it talks about persisting it or not, but the way to do it might be the same):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34219466

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks for help. Running following commands with Shell.su stops adb wireless properly. 

setprop service.adb.tcp.port ""
stop adbd

Comment: glad it helped!